# Laravel 5.4 + jQuery CORS Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, cors

I have two laravel applications, one that acts as an admin panel and the other as an API server.

I am trying to do a jQuery AJAX Post request to the API but the behaviour of the responses seem totally weird.

I am using barryvdh/laravel-cors to enable CORS on the API. I also tried to disable it and add the "options" request manually but I still get the same behaviour.

The issue appears to be with the requests that are made after the preflight request. Here is the order of how they are sent (note that the inital request is a POST):

- The preflight request (OPTIONS - works fine)
- A GET request to the API endpoint (no idea why it does it). It returns a 302 Found redirect back to the referer (to the client)
- A POST request to the API endpoint. Same 302 redirect back.
- An OPTIONS request to the admin url from which the request is sent (Which fails because of no CORS on the admin app).

Here is an image with the flow of the request:
[Request Flow (Chrome network panel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC3rh.jpg)

I have to mention that I do not do any redirects in the controller nor added any middleware that would do it.

Comment: Can you look at the server logs? Also do you have mod security turned on. If so look at the mod sec logs.

Comment: The logs do not show anything. I did notice that the problem is caused by the laravel validator. But that should throw a 400 Bad request.

Comment: I don't know about mod sec, I am running them on localhost under XAMPP. I can check if you think it is relevant.

Comment: Maybe no relevant if just running XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

So aparently, none of the methods that determine if the request must be answered as JSON worked in this case, specifically $request->ajax() and $request->wantsJSON();

I fixed the issue by overriding the function buildFailedValidationResponse on my base ApiController by making it always return a JSON response.

```
protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors)
{
    return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
}
```